# How to write file path into json file in java

Tags: java, json

I have a text which contains file path location. When I am trying to write this text path into a other json file using JSON object put method , I am getting `\\` while my original text path contains `\`.

How can I avoid `\\`?

Please assist me on this.

Comment: You don't,  otherwise it's invalid json.

Comment: What do you expect? ``\`` is an escape char in json, so if you want a literal backslash, you have to escape it to ``\\``. You have no choice in this. If you don't, then your json is either corrupted, or your data-in-json is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the slashes, because that's how the JSON standard is defined for when you show the entire object as a string. If you extract the string from the JSONObject then the slashes are removed.

Edit: to find out the rules for how JSON changes string to it's own notation for "internal" use, see http://json.org/ for the string type.

Still if you want to remove slash use string.replace from java or any other libraries or simply escape the character